# mysql displaying data from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want show field status , jumlah, harga, and total.

this is my structure of table

**order**  `{id_order, id_user, status}`

**order_detail** `{id_order,jumlah, harga, total}`

this is my query function:

```
function shopstat($user_id) {
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * from order_detail left join order on order_detail.id_order=order.id_order where order.id_user=$user_id");
}
```

but I have an error syntax :

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order on order_detail.id_order=order.id_order where order.id_user=16' at line 1

Comment: Heres the standard comment: You are leaving yourself open to SQL injection. You probably want to use `mysqli` `prepare()` function.

Also, for something complex you might want to try using a stored procedure.

Comment: If there is validation of inputs before the query, a stored procedure is not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved word, for `ORDER BY`. You must wrap it in backticks. I also used aliases `o` and `od` so you don't have to make even more backticks. More characters = more likelihood for a typo, but that part is up to you.

```
$query = "SELECT * from order_detail od
          LEFT JOIN `order` o ON od.id_order=o.id_order 
          WHERE o.id_user=$user_id";

return $this->db->query($query);
```

The complete list of reserved words are here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html ( From Fouad )

Answer (score 1):

order is a reserved word in MySQL. See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

"Order" is a reserved word you can't use it as identifier. Use something else instead